# DO I really need to log out of MMA SE to use another identity in other SE fora?

Tags: support

Up until a couple of weeks ago I was logged in SE with two different identities. This one for MMA, Math, Physics and a 'secret' one for drugs, weapons and sex (or something like that...).
I was able to move from one website to the other keeping my respective identities (no action was required). So when I was in MMA SE I was Peltio and when I was in the "nakedgirls SE" I was "Mr.Hyde" (so to speak).

Then something happened: I found myself still logged in the MMA SE group but out of the other. I discovered that the only way to get in the 'other' SE website was to log off SE and then logging in again - inputting user name and password.

Happiness ensued.
Until I tried to log in MMA SE again.
Then I found out I was logged out of *that* group of SE websites.
Again, I have to log off one group and then log in the other, losing the identity in the first group of SE websites.

Is there any way I can automatically switch between identities (without having to log out and then log in) as I have done until a couple of weeks ago?

Is this a new bug, or a new feature?

Comment: If you use googles browser, one way might be to go into [porn mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en). With this you can use your main-identity to always stay logged in and for *sex, drugs and rock&roll* you open an incognito window with `Ctrl+Shift+N` and log in. This saves you at least one log in and two log-outs for an identity switch cycle ;-)

Comment: I was hoping this was some sort of broken behavior, but it appears Big Brother wants every site we've asked questions on to be known to everybody. Bad move. (And thanks for the suggestion, but I use Palemoon - I could not even stand Firefox anymore :-) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: [Global auth is dead! Long live universal login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260153/158428)

> **But I use multiple accounts! What do?**
>
> We aren't intending to break the ability to run multiple accounts. The
>   same guidelines as before still apply - we don't officially support
>   that, you might end up with an accidental automatic merge if you're
>   not careful with your credentials, any interaction between the
>   accounts is right out, and so on.
>
> If you're already using different browsers or different browser
>   profiles for your accounts, nothing will change for you. If you are
>   somehow logged into multiple accounts in the same browser... I'm sorry
>   to say, but that's a bug even for our current global auth setup. You
>   will now only be able to log into one at a time, and you'll need to
>   log out when you want to switch. (Or start using different browsers.)

See the answers as well as the comments for an ongoing discussion about this.  If you wish to voice an opinion about this you should post in the main Meta thread linked above.

Comment: Thanks, I don't like it, but that's what I was looking for. I tried to find a StackExchange website where to ask my question in the list, but could not find it. So it is "Meta", right in the middle of the list... They should put it on top, along with the site-specific Meta...